# Судно́ чи су́дно?

Tags: наголос

Натрапила на сайті "Слово і діло" на статтю ["Підсумки тижня від Віктора Трегубова. Тиждень засудження"](https://www.slovoidilo.ua/2017/01/09/kolonka/vyktor-trehubov/polityka/pidsumky-tyzhnya-vid-viktora-trehubova.-tyzhden-zasudzhennya) журналіста, блогера Віктора Трегубова.

У статті є таке речення:

> Також на тижні стало відомо, що Печерський районний суд наклав арешт
>   на житловий будинок, квартиру, два гаража і **судно (наголос на перший
>   склад)** побіжного екс-президента Віктора Януковича. Той, як і його
>   вишезгадані колеги, звинувачується в держзраді, а також у пособництві
>   замаху на територіальну цілісність України і розв'язування агресивної
>   війни.

Взагалі, враження таке, що вся стаття - це переклад з російської через Google Translator (тільки в цьому абзаці очевидні помилки - `на тижні` (`на неделе`?), `два гаража`, `побіжного` (`беглого`?), `вишезгадані`).

Втім, питання наголосу в слові **`судно`** зацікавило.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/sudno), на жаль, не зазначає наголос у цьому слові (для жодного із двох значень).

**Тож чи орфоепічні норми дозволяють варіативність наголосу в слові *СУДНО* для розрізнення значень?**

Comment: Насправді СУМ-11 задає наголос в обох значеннях (на «о»). Просто в [електронній версії](http://sum.in.ua/s/sudno) іноді є помилки, а наголоси взагалі часто відсутні. Якщо в тій же електронній версії подивитися [відсканований варіант](http://sum.in.ua/p/9/827/1) (посилання внизу сторінки), то навіть там (хоч цей скан із жахливою роздільною здатністю) видно мікроцяточки над «О» — це видно якщо порівняти «О» в значеннях «СУДНО ¹», «СУДНО ²» та «О» в частині складних слів «СУДНО…».

Comment: Цікаво, що Бусел в «[ВТССУМ](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Великий_тлумачний_словник_сучасної_української_мови)» (не плутати з СУМ-20) подає лише одне зі значень «термін військових моряків — плавзасіб» із [наголосом на «у»](http://www.lingvo.ua/ru/Interpret/uk-uk/судно) (див. в «Explanatory (Uk-Uk)»). Але роботу Бусела багато хто лає через некомпетентність/плагіат (хоча мені важко судити так це, чи ні).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Доктор філологічних наук Олександр Пономарів, відповідаючи на запитання читачів ВВС Україна, [зазначає](http://redactor.in.ua/ru/language/7555.Yak_pomilyayutsya_televeduch%D1%96), що правильний наголос - **судно́**.

Підтвердження цьому (для обох значень слова) можна знайти на [Українському лінгвістичному порталі](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

**`судно́ 1`** – іменник середнього роду (*споруда для пересування по воді*)

**`судно́ 2`** – іменник середнього роду (*посудина*)

Один наголос, на **`о́`**, бачимо і в [Орфоепічному словнику](http://www.movi.com.ua/ukrajinski-slovniki/970-orfoepichniy-slovnik-ukrainskoyi-movi) / уклад. М. І. Погрібний. - К. : Радянська школа, 1984. - 629 с.

[image]